# Postman Authentication and Cookie Management

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

I'm looking for any tutorials or blogs related to Auth and Cookie managemnt in postman app. I'm new to Postman so need some guidance.

I'm currently testing an API that follows the following workflow.

visiting portal.site.com it redirects to login.site.com and sets X-csrf token & cookies to it, The login is performed in two steps 1 verify email and then verify password to login and once login is validated you're redirets back to portal.site.com

I have created a postman collection it has 5 total requests

```
1) GET Visiting portal.site.com
2) POST Login Email Validation on login.site.com
3) POST Login Password Validation on login.site.com
4) GET  Redirected back to portal.site.com
5) POST Get Profile Data in JSON response on portal.site.com
```

I need to validate the last request and get the data in response. This can only happen when login is done properly in above requests and cookies are set properly on portal.site.com via login at login.site.com.

If you can share any options on how to do it, I'll be really thankful.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is the authorization-code workflow of OAuth2.
https://auth0.com/docs/flows/authorization-code-flow

Postman supports it as a built-in feature.

[image]